# Not able to use the interface module in Perl

Tags: perl, interface, perl-module, cpan

I'm a beginner in Perl. I am trying to use [CPAN Interface module](http://search.cpan.org/~sinister/Class-Interface-1.01/lib/Class/Interface.pm), but I'm not able to make it work. I have installed the module as per instructions on  [this page](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html).
I'm using EPIC- Eclipse. I'm trying to implement the example given on the same website. The example is as follows:
This is Bouncable interface.

```
  package Bouncable;

  use Class::Interface;
  &interface;   # this actually declares the interface

  sub bounce;
  sub getBounceBack;

  1;
```

and this is the Ball class which implements the Bouncable interface.

```
  package Ball;

  use Class::Interface;
  &implements( 'Bouncable' );

  sub bounce {
    my $self = shift;
    print "The ball is bouncing @ ".$self->getBounceBack." strength"
  }

  sub getBounceBack {
    return 10;
  }

  1;
```

The code is pretty much straight-forward and simple. But im stuck with the following error, and I can't get rid of it.

```
Ball tries to implement non existing interface Bouncable -- Interface Bouncable does not use the interface module. at D:/Eclipse projects/PerlTrial/Bouncable.pm line 4.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 3) line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 3) line 1.
 at D:/Eclipse projects/PerlTrial/Ball.pm line 4.
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: can you run it outside of eclipse? also at the command prompt what happens if you type `perldoc Class::Interface`?

Comment: oh and don't forget `use strict; use warnings;` examples leave it off but you should always use it

Comment: Not able to run it from command prompt as well. I get the same error. When I type perldoc Class::Interface I get the doc page I mentioned in the question above

Comment: I've looked through the module code and you need to remove the whitespace at the front of the lines for `use Class::` and `interface`  I might suggest you use a more modern module such as Moose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module doesn't like white space at the front of its lines

Bouncable.pm

```
use strict;
package Bouncable;

use Class::Interface;
interface;   # this actually declares the interface

sub bounce;
sub getBounceBack;

1;
```

Ball.pm

```
use strict;
package Ball;

use Class::Interface;
implements( 'Bouncable' );

sub bounce {
    my $self = shift;
    print "The ball is bouncing @ ".$self->getBounceBack." strength"
}

sub getBounceBack {
    return 10;
}

1;
```

Comment: As per the module code, dont we have to put a '&' before interface and implements in the above two modules?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view its a copy&paste or Windows linebreak problem. In the interface module line 395 the substitution remove only spaces not whitespaces. The mentioned error message follows immediatly.

```
$line =~ s/\ +$//;
```

should be replaced by

```
$line =~ s/\s+$//;
```

It's only my best guess, can't check it out here. If this doen't work contact the maintainer of this module.